# Creating an Auto Response using Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create an auto response back to the user after they have filled in a Google Form.  So far i have the following code which i have adapted from another user

```
function emailconfirm(e) {
var userEmail = e.values[3]; //email from column D
var firstName = e.values[2]; //first name from column C
var StoreNo = e.values[4]; //last name from column E
var StoreName = e.values[5]; //test name from column F
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 
  "Corporate Order Form Submitted",
  "Thank you " +firstName + ", your Order Form for " +StoreNo +StoreName + "has been submitted. " + 
  "This has been forwarded to the Team for approval. " +
  "Regards ");
```

I am getting to the following message when I debug the code:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you're entering that function in the debugger, you've got no event parameter `e` to give it. The error message isn't lying to you.

See [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067).